# Create an index that is used when searching '%txt'

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql and have a table (`tweets`) which has a text column (`content`). I want to execute the following query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE content ILIKE '%LUCIFERASE';
```

Now I looked through some guides and articles about how an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_content_txt_pattern_ops ON tweets(content TEXT_PATTERN_OPS);
```

won't be used by this query because of the wildcard sign at the beginning. Therefore I found a Generalized Search Tree (GIST) which could technically work so I tried to do it like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_content_gist ON tweets USING GIST(to_tsvector('english', content));
```

Now when I execute the old query I still get a Parallel Sequential Scan, so I tried to write it this way:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE content @@ to_tsquery('%LUCIFERASE');
```

But this query just takes forever (5+ minutes, didn't let it finish) so my question is, am I doing something wrong or is there a some other problem with what I want to do?

EDIT: I want to avoid using trigrams and inverted indexes.

Comment: You can try a [trigram index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) that should be usable with ILIKE

Comment: Ah sorry, I want to avoid using a trigram or an inverted index. Will update question.

Comment: "I am hungry. Can I get rid of that without eating?" Use a trigram index or inverted index.

Comment: But it's the perfect solution for your question: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d45c5d30a4179ede021066c2f4afde26

Comment: Thanks I will do that then, but does that mean those two are the only possible solutions?